# 'diff-pdf.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to use diff-pdf to compare 2 PDF files. Here is the code below. I keep getting the error 'diff-pdf.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

```
import tkinter, sys
import tkinter.filedialog 

programPath = "diff-pdf.exe" 

## START GUI ##
root = tkinter.Tk()         # open and start tkinter object
root.withdraw()             # hide the root window
## save sys.argv arguments (As file dialog changes it...) ##
optArgV = sys.argv[1:] # optional ArgV.

## ASK USER WHICH TWO FILES TO COMPARE ##
filePath1 = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open First PDF - 1")
print ("pdf1: "+filePath1+"\n")  #Display first filepath
filePath2 = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open Second PDF - 2")
print ("pdf1: "+filePath2+"\n")  #Display second filepath

## Run the command line instruction ##
from subprocess import check_output
if ( len(optArgV) > 0 ):   # pass though argument to diff-pdf.exe
print( "ARGUMENTS: "+" ".join(optArgV)+"\n" )
command = programPath+" "+" ".join(optArgV)+" \""+filePath1+"\" 
\""+filePath2+"\""
else:                       # Otherwise default to visual diff
command = programPath+" --view \""+filePath1+"\" \""+filePath2+"\""
print(">> "+command+"\n")
print( check_output( command , shell=True) )

input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Comment: So print the exact command before sending it, and see if `diff-pdf.exe` is in that exact location. It appears it isn't, which means either your command path is incorrect or you don't have `diff-pdf.exe` installed. We can't check either of those things from where we're sitting. The issue is most likely that you're not specifying a directory in the `programPath`, and the directory where the executable is located is not in your system PATH (just like the answer to every other question with this error message has already explained).

Comment: I have 'diff-pdf.exe" in the system path. I have placed my .exe folder in the same folder as my python program, but it is still not working. I am using Python 3.6, Ken White, maybe I should use Python 2?

Comment: So open a command prompt, change to the exact folder where your script is located, and run the exact command line from that prompt. Does it work from there? If not, it won't work from your code either. The Python version is  meaningless; this isn't a Python issue. It's a configuration issue.

Comment: please copy and paste the _exact_ error message.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I did not have "diff-pdf.exe" in my PATH file. This is a rookie mistake and I am a Python rookie.
Thank you,